# How To Efficiently Use Git (GitHub) From a Build Server

Tags: git, github, build-automation

I have a GitHub repository that is a couple hundred megabytes of project  code.  I have a build server that I want to have it pull source from GitHub often and build it. I'm concerned that on every build, I am pulling down to my build server the full GitHub repository.  is there a recommended way to keep my GitHub repository in sync with a repository on my build server so that I only need to pull down the diff's?  It's not obvious how to do that (to me).  Any articles or references would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should configure your build server to not `git clone` repository every time, but just to `git fetch` the branch that you want to build. This way, only the initial clone operation will be costly, subsequent fetches will only fetch deltas and be much faster.